# Copy dates into multiple sheets based on same equipment number

Tags: excel, copy, formulas

I'm sure this is has a simple answer but it's stumping me and I'm not quite sure what to do.

I have a spreadsheet that when I put a date into a column for a certain Equipment # I want it to automatically copy in that date on multiple sheets. My problem is I need it to copy the date for the same equipment #, not cell.
Sheet 1
Equipment # is in Column C, date is in Column Y.

Sheet 2
Equipment # is in Column B, date is in Column P.
I need dates in Y & P to match but on the same Equipment #.

[Worksheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDDAB.jpg)
[Worksheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO8fG.jpg)
I am manually putting in the "Tech Review" dates on each sheet, what I'd like is to put in the date on Sheet 1 and it automatically fill it in on sheet 2 for the same Equipment #.

Comment: Possibly VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH, but it is hard to give more specific answer without seeing a mock up of your data and expected outcome.

Comment: I'm new to this forum, I added pictures of the 2 worksheets. I don't know if that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula into the date field on Sheet2 and copy down as needed.....

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!C:Y,23,1)
```

Comment: That works but is pulling the wrong date, I had some rows hidden in that picture but lets use that and say I also have a date in Column X, that's the date its pulling.

Comment: =VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!C:Z,24,1)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with a Match/Index formula.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDEX('CUI & Paint Combine'!Z:Z,MATCH(B7,'CUI & Paint Combine'!C:C,0))),"",INDEX('CUI & Paint Combine'!Z:Z,MATCH(B7,'CUI & Paint Combine'!C:C,0)))
```

Thanks!